# Node voltage increases in voltage divider

Tags: voltage-divider, biasing, capacity, common-collector

I am planning to use a voltage divider in order to measure the capacity of a group of lithium batteries; in order to minimize power consumption, I biased a common-emitter switch (Q1) with the aforementioned voltage divider attached to its collector so that current would only flow when a signal is sent from the micro-controller (STM32F103).

The problem that occurred was that  the node V1 (schematic below) is pulled to 12 V when the switch(Q1) is off while the ADC of the MCU can only handle 3.3 V. In order to counter-act that, I placed another transistor which is activated by the same base signal in the configuration down below; one thing I noticed however was that the voltage at the node V1 seemed to increase by 0.2V (2.62V without Q2) and Q2's VBE was about 0.5 V even though no current is flowing.

How is that possible if little to no current is flowing through the collector-emitter and base-emitter paths ?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQXCHV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I don't know what's happening with the V1 but Q2 is an emitter follower. The emitter voltage will be a few hundred millivolts below the PB1 voltage. Stick a CircuitLab voltmeter onto ADC1 and connect the base to a 3.3 V source and see what readings you get.

Comment: I get exactly 2.946V in the simulation while IRL I get about 2.88 V.

Comment: Correct. Do you understand what the problem is with that design then? Where is the switch mentioned in your question?

Comment: unfortunately, I do not.

Comment: Think of Q2 as being two diodes; one B -> E and one B -> C. When PB1 goes high (3.3 V) the B -> E junction is forward biased and current can flow to ADC1. The analog input is a very high input impedance so it doesn't draw significant current so the voltage drop is small. (It would be about 0.6 or 0.7 V if you were drawing tens of mA.) Does that make sense?

Comment: No, V1 is an ideal voltage source so it should remain at 12.6 V no matter what. If you've got something else in real life then you need to add it to the schematic along with the switch. Bedtime in Ireland. Good night!

Comment: @Transistor goodnight and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're not measuring the capacity, you're measuring the voltage. In any case, I think you meant the "state of Charge", not "capacity". They are both measured in Ah, but capacity is equivalent to the size of a bucket, and SoC is equivalent to the amount of water in it. If all you are doing is measuring the voltage, you'll not be able to convert that to State of Charge: the voltage of a Li-ion cell is too constant vs. SoC. Therefore, the SoC estimate will be way off.

Second, that approach is ... cumbersome. The way to disable a voltage divider is with a MOSFET (or even a JFET). Use a P-channel MOSFET between the B+ of the string of cells and the top of the voltage divider. Connect the gate to the drain with a 1 MOhm resistor. Drive the gate with a low side switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHIL7N.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A problem with the BJTs that you are using in your circuit is that the base current affects the measurement. A MOSFET doesn't have any gate current, so it doesn't affect the measurement.

Third, that's a Li-ion battery (rechargeable) not a Lithium battery (not rechargeable).

Fourth, that's not "a group of lithium batteries", that's a single battery composed of a group of Li-ion cells.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions you've put out ( I will definitely use a p-mosfet instead) but I'm still unsure about the reason why V1's voltage drifts even though no current is flowing through the base (tested by detaching the emitter of Q2 from the ADC and leaving it in a high impedance state).

Comment: You keep on referring to node V1, but there's no node labeled V1 in that schematic. That's why we can't answer.

Comment: It seems  I forgot to name it, I Apologize for the confusion caused by this,i will definitely fix it , the node V1 is the node after the 33k resistor.

Comment: Thank you. Now, please fix this garbled sentence: "seemed to increase by(2.62V without Q2)0.2V and Q2's VBE was 0.5 V." Please rewrite it so it makes sense. Please let me know when you have done so

Comment: It has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> the voltage at the node V1 seemed to increase by 0.2V (2.62V without Q2)

Because when you add Q2, it takes some of the base current from Q1, which is no longer fully turned on, therefore its collector voltage increases, which in turn increases the voltage at the node V1.

> Q2's VBE was about 0.5 V even though no current is flowing.

That is not a good assumption. An A/D input does pull in some current. That is why we try to keep low the source impedance driving an A/D input. Whenever the A/D input samples, it pulls current through its input, to charge a sample-and-hold capacitor.

> Emitter of Q2 detached and left floating

In that case, there's a lot of radio frequency noise in your area, the meter leads are acting as an antenna, and the transistor is rectifying it, which generates a voltage.

Comment: As I said above, even when tested on a high impedance state ( emitter of Q2 detached and left floating) there was still a voltage drift.

Comment: Emitter detached? And you read 0.5 V between the base and the emitter? Are you sure? If so, please read the edit I made to my answer.

Comment: I am sure of it , my guess for now is that the current was actually flowing from the base to the collector through the CB diode ( 0.5V drop across it ) which actually causes the drift in V1 . in addition, the voltage seen at the emitter of Q2 is equal to V1 ( VCE=0 V), which is also an indication that no current is flowing through the base to the emitter, but rather the voltage at V1 moving to the emitter just as  would happen if we were to put one end of a resistor at a node and measure that same node voltage at the floating end of it.

Comment: And I wouldn't know about radio frequency noise in my area. But one thing is for sure, I live pretty far away from any radio station. I personally do not think that hypothesis is correct  but you never know.

Comment: Place a 10 kOhm resistor in series with each of your meter probes. If you still see 0.5 V, I was wrong. If it drops to 0 V, I was onto something.